# Updating SDK to 25 starts giving ClassNotFoundException error message

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, noclassdeffounderror

I was using SDK 23 in my project and everything was working fine.

This was my gradle file when everything was working fine.

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
      applicationId 'com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

I have updated it to API 25

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
      applicationId 'com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

So now it runs the project successfully, but one of my activity which is  using Google VR has started giving me following error messages.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.example.app, PID: 32413
                                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView$Options;
                                                                     at com.example.app.ThreeSixtyActivity.<init>(ThreeSixtyActivity.java:97)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView$Options" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.app-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is the line where its giving error message

```
/** Configuration information for the video. **/
private Options videoOptions = new Options();
```

The error is  only happening on lollipop devices, Marshmallow is working fine.

Comment: do you have some luck with this?

Comment: @AndrewS , No, still trying to find out the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that really helps to use latest libraries is here:

```
public class AppClass extends Application {

//this will initialize multidex in your own Application class
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}